# VS Code TypeScript Jest Module Mappings

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, ts-jest

I use **TypeScript** with Jest in **VS code** and I have mapped some module paths for easier access to those modules.

Very simplified, my directory structure looks like this:

```
├── app
│   └── middleware
│       └── auth.ts
├── jest.config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── test
│   └── unittest
│       └── app
│           └── middleware
│               └── auth.test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

And I have these mappings i my `tsconfig.json`:

```js
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
        "@app/*": [
        "./app/*"
    ]
}
```

And these mappings in my `jest.config.js`:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/$1"
}
```

Everything works fine and I can run Jest without problems, but VS code does not recognise the `@app` mapping in the file `auth.test.ts` (in `auth.ts` it works fine).

Is there a way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can use the package [module-alias](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/module-alias%20module-alias) to assign your aliases at runtime and then by utilizing Jest's option of setupFile ensure that they are always created at runtime of Jest.</s>

Edit: Issue required another solution that was arrived at in the comments to this answer

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not help. Because this only changes the runtime behavior (which is fine, my tests run without it) and VS code does not recognize the plugin.

Comment: I'm sorry, then I misunderstood. Am I understanding then that in your `auth.test.ts` VSCode is not detecting `@app/middleware/auth.ts`? Comparing your alias paths to where I use them in my own projects where it does work the only difference I can spot is that I do not prefix with `./` (from `./app/*`). Well that and that my way of working is to work from a base of `src` and `__tests__` as per the Jest default spec. I would suggest you try to remove the `./` prefix for starters - I can imagine it might be incorrectly referring to `test/unittest/app`.

Comment: Removing ```./``` did not help, but moving to ```__test__``` did! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you managed to resolve it. The `**/__test__/**` pattern comes from the [default of the testMatch option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string). I've edited my original answer to refer to the comments. You don't have to at all, but I would appreciate it if you'd consider marking the answer as the accepted one.